# Crash when using Core Plot library

Tags: ios, graph, plot, core-plot, linegraph

Basically, I encounter a crash when using the Core Plot. According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki/Using-Core-Plot-in-an-Application) about how to install the `CorePlot` static library, I just drag the `CorePlotHeaders` file and the `libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a` into my project. Then I add the `QuartzCore` and Accelerate framework. Then I have changed the "Other Linker Flags" to "-Objc" and "-all_load".

I have written this code:

```
- (void) configLineGraph
{
    CGRect graphFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.graphView.frame.size.width, self.graphView.frame.size.height);

    // The graph should be put into a hosting view
    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]init];
    [hostingView setFrame:graphFrame];

    // Add it to the view
    [self.graphView addSubview:hostingView];

    // Draw with CPTGraph
    // This is a line graph
    CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]init];
    [graph setFrame:hostingView.frame];

    // Add the graph to the hosting view
    [hostingView setHostedGraph:graph];

    // Draw the scatter plot
    CPTScatterPlot *scatterPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init];
    [scatterPlot setFrame:graph.bounds];

    // Add the scatter plot to graph
    [graph addPlot:scatterPlot];
    [scatterPlot setDataSource:self];

    // Setup the plot space
    // Location is the initial value
    // Length is the range
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) scatterPlot.plotSpace;
    [plotSpace setXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([voltageDataArray count] - 1)]];
    [plotSpace setYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.55)]];

}
```

However, when I run my project, it crashes with the message:

```
2015-07-02 16:59:44.435 Ansmann[4952:236111] -[CPTTextStyle attributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97a1e26a90
2015-07-02 16:59:44.439 Ansmann[4952:236111] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTTextStyle attributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97a1e26a90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac8dc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a56abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac950ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abeb13c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abeacd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Ansmann                             0x0000000109ce7d7b -[CPTAxis updateAxisLabelsAtLocations:inRange:useMajorAxisLabels:] + 1259
    6   Ansmann                             0x0000000109ce93b1 -[CPTAxis relabel] + 1457
    7   Ansmann                             0x0000000109ceac7b -[CPTAxis layoutSublayers] + 75
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000109f536d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000109f53546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ebf886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ec0a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b2c6a2d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b2c76f1 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2648
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b2c60d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001101bf5e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abc141c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abb7165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abb6f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010abb6366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b2c5b42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b2c8900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  Ansmann                             0x0000000109c95e7f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cdda145 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

To install CorePlot, you can use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)

Just add line pod 'CorePlot' to Podfile and run pod install.

Also, please add code used to setup array "voltageDataArray" and what class used for "graphView" ?

Answer (score 0):

The linker flags should be `-ObjC` and `-all_load` (note the capital "C").